# Difference and impact of position:relative, position:absolute, and float

Tags: css, frontend

Can anyone explain the difference of using position:relative, position:absolute, and float in terms of its impact on the normal document flow and its children items?

e.g. When I have three items A,B,C where A is the parent item containing B and C. If I make A position:relative, B position:absolute, C position:absolute, and float both B and C to its left. I find B and C will overlap each other. However I want them to be placed in a serial order contained in A. If I simply dismiss C's position:absolute, they are placed in the right order.  So can anyone summarize the impact of these three out of this simple case, and furthermore, if B and C both have children elements, what impact will they have? (like will them be taken out of normal document flow as well?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Position:absolute` and `float` do not coincide. If you position an element absolutely it is then no longer "floating". i.e. absolutely positioned items (or fixed items) are taken out of the flow of the document.

It is generally better to position things statically or relatively unless necessary. Absolute positioning has its uses, but is not generally needed.

Relative positioning is useful when you need to position a child element *relative* to the parent. So if A is positioned relatively, then positioning B absolutely will mean it is placed based on A's position.

So:

```
A {
    position:relative;
}

B {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:20px;
}
```

Will place B 30px from the top and 20px from the left of A's upper left corner.

Anything then positioned within B, will be based on B's position. If you have B1 inside B, it will be placed relative to B's position, either floated left or right, or positioned absolutely within B (unless it is position:fixed, which is always relative to the viewport).

Is that the sort of explanation you were after?

Comment: Thanks so much! that's exactly what I was looking for. Just some follow-up. any combination of A being relative and its child element, say B being relative as well? And flow occupies space in the normal document flow?(whereas absolute positioning doesn't)?

Comment: Relative positioning means that the element can be floated within its container (or just placed within the normal document flow). What is different between relative and static (the default) is the child elements can be placed absolutely *relative* to it. Relative elements can also receive `top` `left` `right` and `bottom` values that will place them relative to where they would be (but still in the flow). Basically like just adding margins. Yes, absolute and fixed positioned items are outside the flow of elements, all others are inside.

Comment: And also, if I make A position:relative. and its children element B and C flow. Will B and C constrained in the area of A, as is the case when I make B and C absolutely positioned?

Comment: B and C would try to fit within A, yes. You can move them outside of A by using negative margins, of course. No reason to make A `position:relative;` if B and C are simply going to flow within it (only really need relatively positioned elements if something within it needs to be absolutely positioned). B and C can be positioned outside of A when absolute, too, by using negative values in positioning. But they will still be positioned based on the position of A.

Comment: Thanks! better apprehended now